# SPO 2013 - Default Permission Groups

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, groups

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

This question might sound a bit silly, but is there any downsides of removing **ALL** the default permission groups from Sharepoint Online and creating our own? There are default groups such as the Hierarchy Manager that we just don't need. I remember I read from somewhere that there might be complications if those default groups were removed.

I have been trying to think about it and can't come up with any logical reasons why there should be any problems. Still I wanted to make sure and ask around in here to see if someone has good or bad experiences regarding this matter!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can always delete the existing permission groups and create new ones. But I suggest you first create the custom permissions and then delete the existing ones.

Comment: Yep that's what I thought but just didn't trust myself enough to begin removing the default groups without double-checking! Thank you. :)